# not understood the answer of this code snippet(java)

Tags: java

```
class C{
    static int f1(int i) {
        System.out.print(i + ",");
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        i = i++ + f1(i);
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

how come the answer is 1,0.
Please explain.

Comment: did you try to debug it step-by-step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = i++ + f1(i);
```

first i is incremented to 1 and call **f1(1)** and there you print **i ,** which prints **1 ,** and returns 0 which stores in **i** of main method by calculating **0 + 0** and you print it in main so the output becomes **1, 0**

Comment: Note that the value of the expression `i++` is the value of i before it got incremented, so `i = i++ + f1(i)` will be `i = 0 + f1(1)`

Answer (score 5):

Look at the expression:

```
i = i++ + f1(i);
```

One thing you need to understand here is what exactly `i++` does and returns: it increments `i`, but returns the **old** value of `i`. So if `i == 0`, then `i++` increments `i` to `1`, but the resulting value of the expression is `0`.

In Java, expressions are evaluated from left to right. So in the above expression, `i++` is evaluated first, and then `f1(i)`.

After `i++`, `i == 1` so `f1(i)` is actually `f1(1)`. This method prints the value of `i`, which is `1`, with a comma after it, and returns `0`.

Since `i++` returns the old value of `i` (before it was incremented), the expression becomes:

```
i = 0 + 0;
```

The first `0` is the result of `i++`, the second `0` is the result of `f1(i)`. So, `i` is assigned `0`. Finally, you print the value of `i`.

Comment: +1 i++ increments value but returns old value.